# importing rdf in 4store

Tags: rdf, ipv6, triplestore, 4store

I am trying to add triples in triplestore 4store with

```
      4s-import demo new1.rdf
```

but I am getting this error

```
       4store[20652]: 4s-client.c:129 kb=demo getaddrinfo failed for “fe80::227c:8fff:fe32:518d%wlan0” with error: Address family for hostname not supported
       4store[20652]: 4s-client.c:129 kb=demo getaddrinfo failed for “fe80::f24d:a2ff:fe58:86e9%eth0” with error: Address family for hostname not supported
```

I searched and found it is related to ipv6 problem but could not find proper solution for the same

Comment: could you provide a small sample `new1.rdf` that shows this behavior?

Comment: [apparently you should stop `4s-httpd` before the import.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/4store-support/1soAFzqNy-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [import of rdf data in 4store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658547/import-of-rdf-data-in-4store)